# Determining Browser Type and Version for Major Modern Browsers

Tags: javascript

I only support major modern browsers.  Primarily b.c. I currently have limited resources and I have to support what I can and hit the browsers with the most users.  My app only works with JavaScript turned on and a major modern browser.  I have a JavaScript test in place and now I need to test for browser type and version for these browsers.

- IE
- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox

Google search pulls up:

[W3](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) and [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Quriksmode looks to cover too many bases for my needs and W3 I've been told is not the best reference.

The simplest solution I found and what I'd like to use is:

```
navigator.appName
```

to test for the type and

```
navigator.appVersion
```

to test for the version.  Will this work for the limited cases I want to cover?

I don't want to use any libraries.

Comment: i think the choice is up to you whether to use javascript many forms or the jquery or other libraries what did you mean the best reference there are no clue`s  to figure whats best for you ? either javascript or JQuery

Comment: I'm just trying to see if anyone has used navigator.appName and or navigator.appVersion with success...as Quirksmode sais they are not standardized.

Comment: Are you fixed on browser detection? It is generally considered better to use feature detection and not browser detection for better maintainability and more logical code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your limited resources, consider using a framework like jQuery that attempts to manage the sometimes significant differences between browsers on your behalf.

Even if you don't want to use jQuery in general, I would still suggest having a look at it's browser detection capability

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Note that the .browser property is deprecated and may not be available in future versions of jQuery, because the team is focused not on specific browser versions, but on capabilities of the current browser

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

You would be wise to adopt a similar approach.

Comment: I've heard this..just test for the properties you are going to use...but I think Browser self-identification is important too.

Comment: I was planning on using navigator.AppName and navigator.AppVersion...any info. on these?